# How can adapt my one digit calculator to work with any numbers of any length (real)

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

So I have this code, and I've been trying to adapt it to work with any amount of real numbers, it seems that studying the MSFT website hasn't worked out so I'm here as for my last resort.

```
char operation;
String calculation;
double num1, num2, ans;

Console.WriteLine("Place your calculation in the form (x'symbol'y)");
calculation = Console.ReadLine();
num1 = double.Parse(calculation[0].ToString());
num2 = double.Parse(calculation[2].ToString());
operation = calculation[1];

switch (operation)
{
    case '+':
        ans = num1 + num2;
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        ans = num1 - num2;
        Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        ans = num1 / num2;
        Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        ans = num1 * num2;
        Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: the string.Split() method should be a good fit for your problem...

Comment: Simple: `decimal result = (decimal)(new DataTable().Compute(Console.ReadLine(), null))`. ;-)

Comment: It raises an exception when you cast the object typed output to double or decimal, the result must be parsed from a string: `double result = double.Parse(new DataTable().Compute(Console.ReadLine(), null).ToString());` @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @Innat3: then it's much better to use `Convert.ToDecimal(....)` instead of string conversions which are less efficient and could also cause localization issues. So store the `Compute`-result in an `object` variable and then use `Convert.ToDecimal`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter yes that works too! I didn't know it was more efficient

Comment: @Innat3: parsing a string to number is a complex task, casting it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to make it work with numbers of any lengh by using **Regex** and following the format you supplied. As stated in the comments, **Compute()** is a far simpler way to make it work though!

```
        char operation;
        string calculation;
        double num1, num2, ans;
        Regex validcheck = new Regex(@"^\d+([+]|[-]|[/]|[*])\d+$");
        Regex findnumber = new Regex(@"\d+");
        Regex findoperation = new Regex(@"([+]|[-]|[/]|[*])");

        Console.WriteLine("Place your calculation in the form (x'symbol'y)");

        calculation = Console.ReadLine();

        if (validcheck.IsMatch(calculation))
        {
            num1 = double.Parse(findnumber.Matches(calculation)[0].Value);
            num2 = double.Parse(findnumber.Matches(calculation)[1].Value);
            operation = char.Parse(findoperation.Match(calculation).Value);

            switch (operation)
            {
                case '+':
                    ans = num1 + num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    ans = num1 - num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    ans = num1 / num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    ans = num1 * num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The operation you inserted has an invalid format");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the seventh line of code `num2 = double.Parse(calculation[0].ToString());`
you should've written `num2 = double.Parse(calculation[2].ToString());`
The second part I'm still trying to work out.
**Edit: you changed it as i posted this.**

Comment: Yup, thanks, I got that just a second ago as well :)

Comment: @innat3 can't you use string methods like Substring and IndexOf?

Answer (score 0):

Did something similar, except that I only use one Regular expression, and then indexing the group captures for the numbers and operators.

```
        char operation;
        String calculation;
        double num1, num2, ans;

        Console.WriteLine("Place your calculation in the form (x'symbol'y)");
        calculation = Console.ReadLine();
        Regex testRegex = new Regex(@"([0-9]*)([+-/*])([0-9]*)");
        var match = testRegex.Match(calculation);

        if (!match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid syntax");
            return;
        }

        num1 = double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        num2 = double.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        operation = match.Groups[2].Value[0];

        switch (operation)
        {
            case '+':
                ans = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
                break;
            case '-':
                ans = num1 - num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
                break;
            case '/':
                ans = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                break;
            case '*':
                ans = num1 * num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Yours is better, I'm just a newbie with Regex :/